# Laravel factory How can I input enique value from an array?

Tags: laravel

I have a database table called subject_category, In factory I am trying to insert category from an array.

```
$factory->define(SubjectCategory::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    $subject_category = ["Cat 1", "Cat 2", "Cat 3", "Cat 4", "Cat 5","Cat 6"];

    return [
        'name' => $subject_category[array_rand($subject_category)],
    ];

});
```

Here randomly I am able to insert, But how can I run a loop and insert index 0,1,2,3... to my array length ? How I can add loop here for name column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a static variable inside the function as a counter should work:

```
$factory->define(SubjectCategory::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    static $counter = 0;

    $subject_category = ["Cat 1", "Cat 2", "Cat 3", "Cat 4", "Cat 5","Cat 6"];

    return [
        'name' => $subject_category[$counter++],
    ];
});
```